# JSP form date input field

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've created a basic input form with a number of strings using Spring Web application in Intellij. The form successfully saves to the backend when using strings only so I decided to add a date field in the model and tried to modify to controller/jsp to accept this in the input form (and display in the record list). I'm having problems with the input form not getting the value.

Entity:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date dueDate;

public Date getDueDate() {
    return dueDate;
}

public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}
```

JSP (I assume value should be blank here as I am starting with an empty field to fill in?):

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <form:label cssClass="control-label" path="dueDate">Due Date:</form:label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" path="dueDate" class= "date" name = "dueDate" value = "<fmt:formatDate value="" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todos/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("todo") Todo todo, BindingResult result) {
    System.err.println("Title:"+todo.getTitle());
    System.err.println("Due Date:"+todo.getDueDate());
    todoRepository.save(todo);
    return "redirect:/todos/";
}
```

My debug shows Due Date:null so nothing is being send for my date field from the form when posted. This means that the date field is never saved then the repository save occurs.

Comment: I am not sure why the due date could be `null`, but the value attribute for the input element has quotes which need to be changed to single quote or escaped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to register an InitBinder in your controller to let spring convert your date string to java.util.Date object and set it in command object. Include following in your controller :

```
 @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
    }
```

Modify your jsp with :

```
<input type="text" path="dueDate" class= "date" name = "dueDate" value = "<fmt:formatDate value="${cForm.dueDate}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your model class use the annotation provided by DateTimeFormat by spring

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
private Date birthdate;
```

In your jsp the date will bind automatically without error

```
<form:input path="birthdate" cssClass="form-control" />
```

Note: date format must be dd-mm-yy i.e. 27-10-2017 if you use other format it will cause exception

Answer (score 1):

try using spring input like:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <form:label cssClass="control-label" path="dueDate">Due Date:</form:label>
    <div class="controls">
      <form:input path="dueDate" class="date" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and in `dueDate` input you have:

```
value="<fmt:formatDate value="" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />"
```

this is unused, you have not provided value at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a combination of the solutions above and it seems to work (persists and returns the value correctly to the screen). My jsp is:

```
   <div class="control-group">
        <form:label cssClass="control-label" path="dueDate">Due Date:</form:label>
        <div class="controls">
            <form:input path="dueDate" class="date" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I've added the Initbinder described above.

As this is an input form for insert (not update) I don't want to include a value on the for (yet!).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an InitBinder here :
First modify you jsp like Rishav Basu said :

`<input type="text" path="dueDate" class= "date" name = "dueDate" value = "<fmt:formatDate value="${cForm.dueDate}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />"/>`

because you didn't give any value into your input.

Then change your @DateTimeFormat in your entity like this :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Spring will do the binding.

Of course, it works only if you use the same format for your date in the others views. If not, the InitBinder is required.