# source to convert from must be an instance of java.lang.String; instead it was a java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my spring MVC application, I have one model, Employee having one LocalDate field dateOfBirth. I am sending the model from my controller in an ModelAndView object to my jsp. Here the dateOfBirth is not printed in jsp and the following exception was thrown.

> source to convert from must be an instance of java.lang.String; instead it was a java.time.LocalDate

Here is my jsp snippet display my model object.

```
<form:form id="employeeForm" modelAttribute="command" action="${addEmployee}" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: </td>
                    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date of Birth: </td>
                    <td><form:input path="dateOfBirth"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Designation: </td>
                    <td><form:input path="designation"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

Also I am sending the date in the proper format and hence no need to parse it. The only problem is displaying the date as String.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@DateTimeFormat` annotation in your model class attribute `dateOfBirth` with your desired date format.

**Example:**

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

You can apply the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.lang.Long, Joda-Time value types; and as of Spring 4 and JDK 8, to JSR-310 java.time types too.

see [API Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) for more.

Comment: I have applied the annotation in my model class and it's working fine with the backend. When I try to display it in jsp, "unable to convert from LocalDate to Date" error is thrown. Also when I print LocalDate directly in jsp, it's working fine. But I am not able to display it from command object.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `LocalDate` object to String and then print it.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();//For reference
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd LLLL yyyy");
String formattedString = localDate.format(formatter);
```

That should print 26 May 2017.

Comment: That also I have tried. I have changed my getter method to return the LocalDate field as string. Even then I am getting the same error in the jsp page.

Answer (score -1):

you should define Converters in order to let Spring convert the Strings of your HMTL inputs into Objects of Java. I found this post, I think that could help you: [JSP form date input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787790/jsp-form-date-input-field)

Greetings!

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question, You should include some example code. see: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hi.. This method is working fine for input from jsp to controller. But when data is passed from controller to jsp, it is still not working. Now another error message "unable to convert from LocalDate to Date" is thrown. In InitiBinder I have used LocalDate for binding.